# how to invoke macrodef in cumstom ant task with params?

Tags: ant, task, macrodef

I want to create a custom ant task, it reads from a file to get a list params, then traverse list to invake macrodef with list item as param.
how to invoke macrodef in cumstom ant task with params?

Comment: I think that you can find the answer here http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html. Macros are for simple solutions (but in most cases they are sufficient). In macro you can use only other created tasks (it works like composite component in Facelets). If you want to do more complicated operation you can create task by writing your own java class. It's easy, all you need to do is to implement Apache Ant interface. More info here http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html.

Comment: I have already created a custom ant task and runned correctly.i want to know how to invoke macrodef in java code.

Answer (score 1):

From within your custom task, you can call

```
        org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance macro = (org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance) getProject().createTask("myMacroName"); 
        macro.setDynamicAttribute("name", value);
        macro.execute();
```